# Error while building webrtc native on ubuntu

Tags: android, webrtc, ubuntu-15.04

As per the steps given in `webrtc-blueprints` book. I was downloading the `WebRTC` code from the `repo` using following command -

```
gclient config http://webrtc.googlecode.com/svn/trunk
```

**Command resulted into following error.**

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:/dev/libjingle$ gclient config http://libjingle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk
    depot_tools update failed. Conflict in /dev/webrtc/depot_tools
    Cannot rebase: You have unstaged changes.
    Please commit or stash them.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/dev/webrtc/depot_tools/gclient.py", line 2333, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))
    File "/dev/webrtc/depot_tools/gclient.py", line 2319, in main
    return dispatcher.execute(OptionParser(), argv)
    File "/dev/webrtc/depot_tools/subcommand.py", line 252, in execute
    return command(parser, args[1:])
    File "/dev/webrtc/depot_tools/gclient.py", line 1911, in CMDconfig
    client.SaveConfig()
    File "/dev/webrtc/depot_tools/gclient.py", line 1295, in SaveConfig
    self.config_content)
    File "/dev/webrtc/depot_tools/gclient_utils.py", line 142, in FileWrite
    with codecs.open(filename, mode=mode, encoding='utf-8') as f:
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/codecs.py", line 884, in open
    file = __builtin__.open(filename, mode, buffering)
    IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: './.gclient'
```

Comment: IO permissions of /dev/webrtc were root user permissions.. By changing IO permissions to ubuntu user resolved the issue..